# Selecting columns to insert into table with where condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a project where I need to grab the img path from a backup table and insert it in to the image path column of a new table based on if the item names match up perfectly (as the id's vary).

This is what I tried, but getting an error that the items.prod_name column is not found:

MySQL

```
INSERT INTO items (img_path) 
SELECT img_path
FROM items_backup 
WHERE items.prod_name = items_backup.prod_name
```

Comment: I guess you need an UPDATE statement, not INSERT

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to want an `update`, not an `insert`.  The syntax in MySQL is:

```
update items i join
       items_backup ib
       on i.prod_name = ib.prod_name
    set i.img_path = ib.img_path;
```

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on my comment:

```
UPDATE items 
INNER JOIN items_backup ON items.prod_name = items_backup.prod_name
SET items.img_path = items_backup.img_path
```